# jquery plugin -working but while debugging,result is being shown even before reaching that line 

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, coffeescript

my jquery plugin coffee script   :

```
(($) ->

  $.fn.externalify = (options) ->

    console.log "start"
    console.log @    
    settings = $.extend {
      'rel' : 'external' 
    } , options 

    links = $ @selector+" a"
    console.log "---first links--"
    console.log links
    console.log '---first links--'
    if links.length is 0
      if ((@[0].toString().indexOf("http://") is 0) or (@[0].toString().indexOf("https://") is 0))
        unless @[0].host is  window.location.host

        $(@).attr settings
    console.log "---links---"
    console.log links
    console.log '----links---'      
    for i in links
      if (i.toString().indexOf("http://") is 0)or(i.toString().indexOf("https://") is 0)
        console.log "--"
        console.log i
        console.log "--"
        unless i is window.location.host
           console.log "Before : "
           console.log $(i)
           $(i).attr settings
           console.log "After : "
           console.log $(i)

) jQuery
```

code in javascript :

```
 (function() {

(function($) {
  return $.fn.externalify = function(options) {
  var i, links, settings, _i, _len, _results;
  console.log("start");
  console.log(this);
  settings = $.extend({
    'rel': 'external'
  }, options);
  links = $(this.selector + " a");
  console.log("---first links--");
  console.log(links);
  console.log('---first links--');
  if (links.length === 0) {
    if ((this[0].toString().indexOf("http://") === 0) || (this[0].toString().indexOf("https://") === 0)) {
      if (this[0].host !== window.location.host) $(this).attr(settings);
    }
  }
  console.log("---links---");
  console.log(links);
  console.log('----links---');
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = links.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    i = links[_i];
    if ((i.toString().indexOf("http://") === 0) || (i.toString().indexOf("https://") === 0)) {
      console.log("--");
      console.log(i);
      console.log("--");
      if (i !== window.location.host) {
        console.log("Before : ");
        console.log($(i));
        $(i).attr(settings);
        console.log("After : ");
        _results.push(console.log($(i)));
      } else {
        _results.push(void 0);
      }
    } else {
      _results.push(void 0);
    }
  }
  return _results;
};
})(jQuery);

}).call(this);
```

if there is a link like

```
<span><a href="http://google.com">google</a></span> in body tag .
```

if i run , $("span").externalify() , then attributes "rel" : "external" will be added the link , thus making the link as :

```
<span><a rel="external" href = "http://google.com">google</a></span>
```

its working fine, but if u see my code, i have put lot of console.log commands . all of them are printing the new ones with "rel" : "external" , both before and after the operation, it is showing the attriutes, how could that happen .

Comment: hey can you provide the compiled js...not good at coffeescript

Comment: Are you calling multiple times `$.externalify`?

Comment: @Alexander multiple times means,its our wish, we can call any number of times, but for the first time, i think ,at the beginning it should show without adding attributes

Comment: @rameshkumar, it is all around. You mean that after the first time It should ignore the already processed links?

Comment: ok...and one more thing...how is the plugin called? i mean on what elements? can you just give an example?

Comment: @ParthThakkar , we can call divs or span or body or anything that contains links(need not) , for example , $("body").externalify() , will add attrbutes "rel" : "external" to all links that start with http ,

Comment: @Alexander, plz dont get confused,it just take examines the links , and adds attr "rel" : "external"  to links that has href starting with "http or https" , wat i am asking is ,in the beginning of the code,if i output the element, it shouldnt have attr "rel" , but only after crossing the line where the attrites are set in the code, only after that line , we should be able to see atr "rel", its not happening, does it mean, my code is wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

That's a whole lot of code for what is essentially this:

```
$('a').filter(->
    /^http/.test(this.href) and this.href.indexOf(location.host) < 0
).attr(rel: 'external')
```

Instead of a plugin, you might consider implementing a custom pseudo-selector for external links:

```
$.expr[':']['external'] = (elem) ->
    /^(\w+:)?\/\//.test(elem.href) and elem.href.indexOf(location.host) < 0

// usage:
$('.container a:external').attr('rel', 'external')
```

Notice that I replaced the simple 'http' test for a little more complex regular expression; urls that omit the protocol, like `//google.com`, are allowed and increasingly common. The mere presence of `//` at the start is enough to detect an absolute url. This also catches any other protocols besides http.

Answer (score 0):

Why *confusify* when you can *simplify*? Look at the code I've created here: http://jsfiddle.net/aajFj/ It works just fine... Hope it helps.

Comment: `outerHTML ` with RegEx? I hope you are kidding.

Comment: why? what's wrong? did you inspect the links? they work...and the regex, as far as i can tell, will work fine...i've taken special care for extra/no whitespaces...

Comment: if you can tell me the potential problems that can arise, then i can propose to *Cut and assemble the components of* *the symbolic arrangement of data or instructions in a computer program or the set of such instructions* -- i can edit it. :)

Comment: there's no need for `outerHTML`, the function should use `this.href`. The valid link `<a href=//google.com>External</a>` fails as it is.

Comment: I previously thought that would work. But the problem with it is that this.href returns a complete url -- if you have <a href =.